# URL query parameter as a dictionary in Pyramid

Tags: python, dictionary, pyramid, url-parameters

The [JSON API](http://jsonapi.org) specification uses a dictionary like syntax for some [query parameters](http://jsonapi.org/format/#fetching-sparse-fieldsets):

```
GET /articles?include=author&fields[articles]=title,body,author&fields[people]=name HTTP/1.1
```

Is there any easy way to retrieve the above `fields` parameter as a dictionary using Pyramid?

To provide further details, the following `fields` parameters are given:

- `fields[articles]=title,body,author`
- `fields[people]=name`

I'd like to get them all in a Python dictionary:

```
fields = {
    'articles': 'title,body,author',
    'people': 'name',
}
```

Comment: You're gonna need to parse this format yourself. From a quick review of available JSON-API libraries for Python there doesn't seem to be a widely available parser for this format. As @stevepiercy's answer below indicates, there is a semi-hacky way to do it directly from the parsed x-www-urlencoded format that webob understands.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand what you are asking, an example is in the [Pyramid Quick Tour](https://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/en/latest/quick_tour.html#handling-web-requests-and-responses) with links to further examples and the complete Pyramid request API.

Essentially:

```
fields_articles = request.params.get('fields[articles]', 'No articles provided')
fields_people = request.params.get('fields[people]', 'No people provided')
```

Then put them into a dictionary.

**EDIT**

Would this suffice?

```
fields = {
    'articles': request.params.get('fields[articles]', ''),
    'people': request.params.get('fields[people]', ''),
}
```

Comment: I've added more details to my question.